# Integrating AWS Tag Editor with lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I want to get an inventory of all my resources in aws account.I am using aws tag editor for this process,but I would like to automate this process through aws lambda(Using tag editor with lambda)
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your actual question? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS Config to get the list of all AWS resources and not the tag editor.

Two ways can do it

1. CLI - the `aws configservice list-discovered-resources` CLI command is intended to give you a listing of all your resources. Please check the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configservice/list-discovered-resources.html).
2. By using AWS Config console.
   [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/viewing-the-aws-config-dashboard.html) is more info about its usage.

   **To look up resources**

   Go to -> https://console.aws.amazon.com/config/.

   On the Resource inventory page, specify the search options for the resources that you want to look up.

***Note***: Currently AWS Config does not support all the AWS resources, so you might not see some of them.

Comment: Hi,with the help of tag editor, I can manually export the list of all resources with their respective tags.Instead of doing it manually,I wanted to automate the whole process with a python/lambda script maybe.This is my use case.